# xlwings workbook.save(): Error when a file with same name in filepath already exist

Tags: python, xlwings

I am opening an Excel-file wb with xlwings, doing some operations, and then trying to save it to a directory. In the filepath I type in wb.save(), a file with the same name already exist. I want to save the file, but if the filename already exist, I want to overwrite it.

The following code gives me the following error:

```
Some_data = filepath to a file
Original = filepath to another file

df = pd.read_excel(Some_data, engine = "openpyxl")

wb = xw.Book(Original)

ws = wb.sheets["dump"]

ws["B2"].options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=False, expand="table").value = df


wb.save(filepath with filename that already exist and I want to overwrite)
wb.app.kill()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [86], in <cell line: 13>()
      8 ws = wb.sheets["dump"]
     10 ws["B2"].options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=False, expand="table").value = df
---> 13 wb.save(r"C:\Users\FrodeWilkensen\OneDrive - Norfund\Frode Wilkensen\dimped.xlsx")
     14 wb.app.kill()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py:874, in Book.save(self, path)
    872     path = utils.fspath(path)
    873 with self.app.properties(display_alerts=False):
--> 874     self.impl.save(path)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py:582, in Book.save(self, path)
    580 alerts_state = self.xl.Application.DisplayAlerts
    581 self.xl.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
--> 582 self.xl.SaveAs(os.path.realpath(path), FileFormat=file_format)
    583 self.xl.Application.DisplayAlerts = alerts_state

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py:70, in COMRetryMethodWrapper.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     68 while True:
     69     try:
---> 70         v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
     71         if isinstance(v, (CDispatch, CoClassBaseClass, DispatchBaseClass)):
     72             return COMRetryObjectWrapper(v)

File C:\Users\FRODEW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py:46807, in _Workbook.SaveAs(self, Filename, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local, WorkIdentity)
  46804 def SaveAs(self, Filename=defaultNamedNotOptArg, FileFormat=defaultNamedNotOptArg, Password=defaultNamedNotOptArg, WriteResPassword=defaultNamedNotOptArg
  46805         , ReadOnlyRecommended=defaultNamedNotOptArg, CreateBackup=defaultNamedNotOptArg, AccessMode=1, ConflictResolution=defaultNamedOptArg, AddToMru=defaultNamedOptArg
  46806         , TextCodepage=defaultNamedOptArg, TextVisualLayout=defaultNamedOptArg, Local=defaultNamedOptArg, WorkIdentity=defaultNamedOptArg):
> 46807     return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(3174, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (3, 49), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Filename
  46808         , FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup
  46809         , AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout
  46810         , Local, WorkIdentity)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'SaveAs method of Workbook class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Any ideas? All help appreciated.

Comment: As a workaround, you could delete the file first with `import os; os.remove(filepath)`.